# Javascript click through element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a semitransparent overlay `div` covering document which destroys on click, but I need somehow to trigger onlick events of the element beneath overlay at the same time. Is there a way to click on specific coordinates with JS, or maybe determine underlying element having absolute x and y positions? Thanks.

Comment: check out this answer to find the element by coordinates, and then trigger onclick on the found element: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590119/javascript-retrieving-html-control-by-specifying-coordinates/1317387#1317387

Comment: would it be possible when the div element is added, you build a connection of the div element to the element above it. Then when the element above it is clicked, a handler is invoked for the div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330009/nick) has posted a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268791/javascript-click-through-element/3268814#comment-3381183) to awesome answer on how to get elements by x and y but unfortunately it's a comment so I can't accept it. :(

Comment: It might return the semi-transparent div. May be excluding semi-transparent will do the work for you.

Comment: I already got it working as Nick posted his comment, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find out what is the element given the coordinates, you can always trigger the onclick handler yourself with jQuery using the .click() function.

Comment: Sure, but how to determine which element's events I have to trigger?