# How to create a text overlay in Google Maps API v3 that does not pan?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API v3. I would like to create a text overlay on a map that does not move when the map is panned. Is the best approach to manipulate the DOM elements accessible from the MapPanes object or is it best to create a custom control even though it would not do much other than display text?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The simplest way that I found worked for me was a few lines of JavaScript added after I created a new map. So, after this:

```
map = new google.maps.Map('myMapDivId', mapOptions);
```

add this:

```
var myTitle = document.createElement('h1');
myTitle.style.color = 'white';
myTitle.innerHTML = 'Hello World';
var myTextDiv = document.createElement('div');
myTextDiv.appendChild(myTitle);

map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER].push(myTextDiv);
```

You will probably want to style the text to look nicer.

An alternative is to put the div in your HTML:

```
<div id="myTextDiv" style="color: white; position: absolute;">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

and then do this in your JavaScript:

```
var myControl = document.getElementById('myTextDiv');
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(myControl);
```

NOTE an important difference: If you use the HTML route to define your div, you must set the position style to absolute in the HTML to avoid rendering problems.

Comment: position: absolute - is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Any ideas how to click through the appended element, so that the map is draggable under it?

Comment: @yckart - No answers but these two SO questions have answers that I'd pursue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002960/pass-left-click-message-to-html-element-below-another-one and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268791/javascript-click-through-element. Good luck and post back if you're successful.

Comment: @DaveBurns Success... `pointer-events:none` does the trick :)

Answer (score 5):

From you're describing, the best approach would be a custom control. Docs for that are [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#CustomControls). Custom controls can be as simple or a complicated as you want.

One reason why you would want to muck around with the map panes is if you wanted such a 'control' to lie underneath the markers / shadows / polylines etc. I'm doing this right now to show a crosshairs in the center of the map at all times. But because I keep it as an overlay, I choose the panes in such a way that the markers are above it, so they can continue to be clicked and interacted with - using the `mapPane`. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
var CrosshairOverlay = function(map){
    this._holder = null;
    this.setMap(map);
};
CrosshairOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
CrosshairOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function(){
    var map = this.getMap();
    var holder = this._holder = $('<div>').attr('id', 'crosshair')[0];

    var crosshairPaper = this._paper = R(holder, 150, 150);
    // ... all your drawing and rendering code here.
    var projection = this.getProjection();
    var wrappedHolder = $(holder);

    var updateCrosshairPosition = function(){
        var center = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(map.getCenter());
        wrappedHolder.css({left:center.x-75, top:center.y-75});
    }
    _.each(['drag','dragend','bounds_changed','center_changed','zoom_changed','idle','resize'], function(event){            
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, event, updateCrosshairPosition);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'maptypeid_changed', function(){
        _.defer(updateCrosshairPosition);
    });

    this.getPanes().mapPane.appendChild(holder);
};
CrosshairOverlay.prototype.draw = function(){
};
CrosshairOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function(){
    this._holder.parentNode.removeChild(this._holder);
    this._holder = null;
};
```

The reason the `maptypeid_changed` has its own handler with a `defer` is because that event is fired before the map properly sets itself up when changing the type. Just run your function after the current event loop.